Left-Align text on line of lollipop chart
Looking to have a lollipop chart that has what would essentially be the axis-text on top of the line. Right now here's my code:
temp <- data.frame("question" = c("Better meeting planning, i.e. organized with sufficient notice",
                                  "Clearer communication of meeting objectives and agenda",
                                  "Debriefing contributors who did not attend the meeting",
                                  "Having the right participants",
                                  "Meeting Frequency Meeting Duration",
                                  "Meetings starting and ending on time",
                                  "Respect during meetings (behavior and tone of leaders)",
                                  "Sticking to the meeting agenda",
                                  "Taking decisions and clearly defining a call to action"),
                   "n" = c(45, 51, 30, 27, 22, 34, 34, 22, 37), 
                   "per" = c(0.15, 0.17, 0.1, 0.09, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.07, 0.12))

ggplot(temp, aes(reorder(question, per), per,)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=reorder(question, per), xend=reorder(question, per), y=0, yend=per), color="#F7C52A") +
  geom_point(color = "#F7C52A", size=4, alpha=1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = reorder(question, per)),
            size = 3, hjust = 1.05, vjust = -0.9, color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "n", axis.text.x = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  coord_flip()


It's almost there, but the text is right-justified and anchored to the point, which I understand why that would be. Also considered trying to move the text from the x-axis, but couldn't get that to work either.
Thanks!

This may be one way of achieving the desired output; including some edits to the call to ggplot to avoid the coord_flip
library(ggplot2)

temp <- data.frame("question" = c("Better meeting planning, i.e. organized with sufficient notice",
                                  "Clearer communication of meeting objectives and agenda",
                                  "Debriefing contributors who did not attend the meeting",
                                  "Having the right participants",
                                  "Meeting Frequency Meeting Duration",
                                  "Meetings starting and ending on time",
                                  "Respect during meetings (behavior and tone of leaders)",
                                  "Sticking to the meeting agenda",
                                  "Taking decisions and clearly defining a call to action"),
                   "n" = c(45, 51, 30, 27, 22, 34, 34, 22, 37), 
                   "per" = c(0.15, 0.17, 0.1, 0.09, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.07, 0.12))

ggplot(temp, aes(per, reorder(question, per))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, 
                   xend = per,
                   y = reorder(question, per), 
                   yend = reorder(question, per)), color="#F7C52A") +
  geom_point(color = "#F7C52A", size=4, alpha=1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, label = reorder(question, per)),
            size = 3, 
            hjust = 0, 
            vjust = -0.9, 
            color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "n", 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, 
       y = NULL, 
       fill = NULL)


Created on 2024-04-09 with reprex v2.0.2

Thanks, @Peter! This worked perfectly. For my own education was it thanks to correctly calling the x & y axes and having hjust = 0 that solved it? When I'm making a lot of very similar charts sometimes I end up just adding coord_flip() rather than rewriting the code...bad habit I know :)

I also just noticed the x = 0 in geom_text's aes call. That was probably key I'm guessing

Correct because the default x coordinates are given in the call to ggplot(aes()) as per so you need to override that in geom_text(aes()) .

By the way, as a matter of convention; when your question is answered it is customary to click on the accept answer option and upvote if you have sufficient reputation and What does it mean to accept an answer
